# Redirecting to the first item in an Ember array, alphabetically?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got an array of pages that I'm sorting by title like so:

```
PagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sortProperties: ['title']
```

I'm also trying to redirect to the first item in the array when the user hits the `pages.index` route.

```
PagesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: (model) ->
    page = model.get 'firstObject'
    @transitionTo 'page', page if page?
```

Problem is, the `firstObject` is not the first item in the sorted array, so the user is plopped in somewhere in the middle of the list. In the template, I can loop through the `arrangedContent` property in order to get the sorted array. However, in the route, I have no access to that property or the sorted array.

How can I redirect to the first object in the array, **after** the array has been sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access `PagesController` in `PagesIndexRoute`'s `redirect` action via method `@controllerFor('pages')`. Then you can access its sorted content. Please try following code:

```
PagesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: ->
    page = @controllerFor('pages').get 'firstObject'
    @transitionTo 'page', page if page?
```

Comment: That works! Question for you though. Why do I not need to do @controllerFor('pages').get('arrangedContent').get('firstObject')? In the template I have to explicitly loop through the arrangedContent instead of the models.

Comment: Because you use `Em.ArrayController` and you have access to some special properties like `firstObject`, `lastObject` on controller. See [properties available in API docs for ArrayController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html).